# Printing to System.out as UTF-8 regardless of platform default

Tags: java, utf-8, stdout

In Java, `System.out.print` takes encoding from the platform default.

Suppose you want to always print as UTF-8 regardless of the platform default, what's the most idiomatic/efficient way to do this?

The best idea I have so far is to explicitly spell out two steps, first convert string to UTF-8 bytes with `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, then print the bytes with `System.out.write`, which bypasses the question of encoding.

Is this the recommended way, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: You can use an `OutputStreamWriter` on `System.out` with UTF-8 encoding. Bear in mind that's most likely to fail in a Windows console

Comment: Call `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` to make your **out** `PrintStream` use UTF-8. However, if you do that you also need to be writing to a console using UTF-8. On  Windows there are flaky ways to do that (e.g. `chcp 65001`) but there is no general solution for all the types of console that are available on Windows.